# VS Code on rhel/centos should appear in Gnome after install

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, rhel7

I installed VS Code on rhel7 using the instructions here: [Running VS Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

I had done this previously and then had reinstalled the OS. That previous time, the VS Code app appeared in the Gnome list of applications under a section for Development and (I think) under Utilities.

This time VS Code does not appear in the Gnome interface at all.

And then there's the problem of it not opening a file on the command line, even if the path to the executable is in the path... sigh...

However, it does show help in response to 'code -h'. That's a good thing, right?

Has anyone discovered a reliable way to do this install on rhel7/centos7?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, should have guessed: reboot required.

As always, even with RHEL, 'if in doubt reboot' is the too common solution.

To me it means that even 'enterprise' linux is starting to catch up to Windows XP in terms of reliability.

Now, post reboot, VS Code shows up in Gnome under 'Programming' and works fine.

The fabled (now real) 'code .' and 'code file' cli operations will work on RHEL, but only from the Terminal application available on the Gnome 'Applications' dropdown lists.

However, its still not working in a 'regular' terminal, such as the putty connection I usually connect through.

So inside Gnome, command line operations have the GUI 'context'. This is probably the role of the xdg command settings referred to in the link above ([Running VS Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)) which did not work for me on RHEL but probably is designed to work on ubuntu.